# Magento Random Fatal Error

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, hosting, cpanel

I have a VPS apache server based in a farm.

Recently i sufferd from memory limit errors and i decided to increase the number of the memory limit by changing it in the WHM panel at PHP Configuration to 256MB. after i was presss the button "Save", i got my site (and other wordpress sites i have in my server) all over with random fatal errors and 500 internal server errors on my site: http://amadeus-trade.ru

I can log into the backoffice but, when i tried to go to System -> Configuration i get this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@amadeus-trade.ru and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

And when i try to add products i get this error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 19922944) (tried to allocate 1245184 bytes) in /home/amadeus/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php on line 2423

This error allways jumps from file to file and looks like this scheme:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated xxxxxxxx) (tried to allocate xxxxxxx bytes) in /home/amadeus/public_html/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xx/xx.php on line xxxx

Now, It is fresh installation. so far (until 01.11.12) the website worked great without problems.

The team in the hosting company says that this is aproblem of a code in magento but i positivly sure that the problem is on the server!
My WHM version was update by the team in 01.11.12 to v11.30

Can you assist me please how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your error message

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 19922944) (tried to allocate 1245184 bytes) 
in /home/amadeus/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Date.php on line 2423
```

PHP is telling you it tried to allocate 1,245,184 bytes of memory, but that was over the limit allowed.  It's also telling you there are currently 19,922,944 bytes allocated.

1,245,184 bytes is 1,216 kilobytes (KB), which is 1.1875 megabytes (MB).

19,922,944 bytes is 19,456 kilobytes (KB), which is about 19 megabytes (MB).

This means one of two things.

- PHP thinks it's only allowed to allocate around 19 MB of memory
- The operating system PHP is running on ran out of memory

Check your runtime `php.ini` settings to make sure your memory change stuck (use a single page calling the `phpinfo` function to do this).  Also, make sure it's `256M`, and not `256MB`.  The later won't be recognized by PHP, and "weird things" will happen (including a super low memory limit).

That said, my guess is it's the later. When my version of PHP goes over the limit set in the `memory_limit` ini, I get a slightly different error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10493952 bytes)
```

PHP is telling me that it's **allowed** limit has been violated.  Your error

```
Fatal error: Out of memory
```

Says PHP has literally used up all the memory avaiable to the server at that point in time.

Beyond that, you host's response show a lack of Magento specific knowledge — any host capable of running the system would be able to the give you the information I just did.  I'd start by asking them what the maximum memory limit is for a single PHP request.  I'd end by moving to a VPS host that advertising Magento capability and has a good reputation for it.

Comment: Great answer! That help! ll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that 256M was lower than it originally was set to? As it sounds like you already know, Magento requires a minimum of (get this) 256mb of ram, and 512 is recommended, and certainly more for larger applications.

Run a `phpinfo()` command and see what the `memory_limit` property is set to. If you can, use your `.htaccess` to change the limit to a more reasonable level:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

However, I must say that there is a good chance that your hosting provider will frown on changing this setting (if they don't allow you to do it in `.htaccess`).

Comment: First, it would be good to update your question with that piece of information. Secondly, what other extensions do you have installed? How many products do you have?

Comment: Dont have any. It is fresh installation